# Reverse geocoding layer of points but retaining original points

Tags: arcgis-pro, geocoding

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.1 and I wish to reverse geocode a point layer (i.e., I have the points and I want street addresses for them).  When I use the Reverse Geocode tool with the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service, I can get addresses, but the output dataset also contains new geometry (i.e., new points).  I don't want the latter - I want to keep the original points and just get addresses for them.

Is this possible?

Further, when I run the tool, if any records are returned for which an address could not be assigned, those records have no geometry at all.  But I want to keep the original points, even if I can't get an address for them out of the tool.  I'm working with hundreds of records, so the `What's Here?` interactive tool is not practical.

Comment: The output file should not change source attributes but should have added REV_ see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/geocoding/reverse-geocode.htm

Comment: I'm not having any issue with attributes.  It is that the records I put into the tool come out with new geometry - that is, the points in the output are in a different location than the points I put into the tool.  What I will do is to use the attribute table of the reverse geocode output and join it to my original table so that I can copy the addresses into the field where I need them.  This way, I keep my original points and I get the addresses I wanted.  It's just no quite how I expected the tool to work.